# How to install ipython or flask and there dependences in virtualenv?

Tags: pip, virtualenv

I have learned the dependences should be installed automatically, but it only install itself when I install flask in a virtualenv.

```
Installing collected packages: flask
Successfully installed flask-0.12.2

➜  ~ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep 15 2017, 07:44:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask import Flask
Trceback...
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug'
```

Then I have to install werkzeug and re-import Flask

but:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2'
```

After install jinja2, there still markupsafe, itsdangerous (etc) to install to run Flask.

---

#### Solved

*I forgot when did I set 'no-dependences = True' in .pip/pip.conf.*

*Now it's okey after detele the line.*

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you've either

- installed packages into virtualenv but receive these errors when the virtualenv is not activated i.e. when interpreter has no access to those packages

or

- vice versa i.e. installed packages globally and then activated virtualenv, where by default the only pre-installed packages are `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel`.

I would suggest activating the virtualenv [from dir holding venv, run `. <venvName>/bin/activate`] and checking packages available [`pip list`]. Then, deactivate and check global packages available.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I'm sure not installed flask globally, and the virtualenv was created just for the question like you said 'the only pre-installed packages are pip, setuptools, and wheel.'

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I forgot when did I set 'no-dependences = True' in .pip/pip.conf.

Now it's okey after detele the line.